# Using Combine to encode object to httpBody in URLRequest

Tags: swift, combine

Is there a way to use Combine to Encode an object to `urlRequest.httpBody` or return the error from decoding as AnyPublisher with a certain error type.

I'm unable to get this to work and there seems to be no code examples for encoding objects using combine. Having to force cast the encoding error to be AnyPublisher doesn't seem right / is unsafe.

Thanks

```
func create(object: ExampleObject, token: Token) -> AnyPublisher<ExampleObject, API.Error> {

    let url = API.EndPoint.players.url
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    do {
        // is there a safe combine way to encode this
        urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(object)
    } catch {
        // Is there a better way to handle this
        return error as! AnyPublisher<ExampleObject, API.Error>
    }

    return session
        .dataTaskPublisher(for: urlRequest)
        .map(\.data)
        .decode(type: ExampleObject.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .mapError { error in
            switch error {
            case is URLError:
                return API.Error.addressUnreachable
            default:
                return API.Error.invalidResponse
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't have your `API.Error` enum so I've create simple enum for example

```swift
enum APIError: Error {
  case encode(EncodingError)
  case request(URLError)
  case decode(DecodingError)
  case unknown
}
```

```swift
func create<ExampleObject>(object: ExampleObject, token: String) -> AnyPublisher<ExampleObject, APIError> where ExampleObject: Codable {
  return Just(object)
    .encode(encoder: JSONEncoder())
    .mapError { error -> APIError in
      if let encodingError = error as? EncodingError {
        return .encode(encodingError)
      } else {
        return .unknown
      }
  }
  .map { data -> URLRequest in
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: API.EndPoint.players.url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    urlRequest.httpBody = data
    return urlRequest
  }.flatMap {
    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
      .mapError(APIError.request)
      .map(\.data)
      .decode(type: ExampleObject.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
      .mapError { error -> APIError in
        if let decodingError = error as? DecodingError {
          return .decode(decodingError)
        } else {
          return .unknown
        }
    }
  }
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```